How Can I Retrieve NFT Holders wallet using OpenSea API?
I have been looking for this in the OpenSea API documentation but cannot find any endpoint that retrieve the holders and the wallet address for a NFT Collection. For example I want the holders/owner addresses of this collection: https://opensea.io/collection/azuki
Thanks
I tried to use https://docs.opensea.io/reference/list_nfts_by_collection endpoint but it only retrieves the total owner count not the actual addresses.
